# Counting number of unmasked pixels per image in collection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, pixel, count, cloud-cover

I'm trying to count the number of pixels that are masked by the cloud mask of the image collection given by the Earth Engine dataset. I have clipped my collection with a ROI and now I want to keep the images with 10% or less of clouds  (masked pixels). By now, I am only able to count them for a single image but not for the entire collection.

I am now using this code for one image but I am not able to reproduce this for the entire collection.

```js
var Peyto_pixelscount = Peytoclip.first().select('ALBEDO').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: Peyto_glacier.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print(Peyto_pixelscount)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You could also add a working example of your current code and your (erroneous) trials, then the question is quite complete.

Answer (score 12):

To get to your end goal of filtering your clipped image collection by 10% or less cloud cover, I would write a function that:

1. counts the number of unmasked pixels in the image
2. counts the number of pixels in the unmasked image
3. calculates the percentage of masked pixels and sets this as a metadata property

I would then map this onto your image collection and filter it by the added metadata property.

Note that I'm assuming that your images are only masked by a cloud mask.

```
function get_cloud_cover_roi(image){ 

  var Peyto_pixelscount = image.select('ALBEDO').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: image.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).get('ALBEDO')

  var npix = image.select('ALBEDO').unmask().reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: image.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).get('ALBEDO')

  var cloud_cover_roi = ee.Number(1)
      .subtract(ee.Number(Peyto_pixelscount).divide(npix))
      .multiply(100)

  return image.set('cloud_cover_roi', cloud_cover_roi)

}

var Peytoclip_filtered = Peytoclip
    .map(get_cloud_cover_roi)
    .filterMetadata('cloud_cover_roi', 'less_than', 10)
```

Comment: Thank you ! You are awsome.

Comment: Hi @laurent, it looks like this answer satisfies your question. If so, would you kindly accept the answer (click check mark below vote tally) so that question browsers know that this is a completed Q&A. If a more suitable answer comes along in the future, you can always change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Similar logic to the [previous](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/363719/51905) answer but in a function call.

`geom` could be any region in the image, or `image.geometry()` for the whole image.

```
/** 
 * return the percentage of masked pixels in an image region. 
 */
function calculateMaskedPercent(image, band, geom) {
   var maskedPixelCount = image.select(band).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geom,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).get(band);

  var totalPixelCount  = image.unmask().select(band).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geom,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).get(band);
 
  var cloud_cover_roi = ee.Number(1)
      .subtract(ee.Number(maskedPixelCount).divide(totalPixelCount))
      .multiply(100)
  return cloud_cover_roi;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote that to python (which I needed) and it solved my problem!

Comment: Glad its helpful. You can post your python code as another answer.